# Subset of unary recursive functions is not recursive if it and its complement are non empty.

Tags: computability, recursion, recursive-algorithms

Suppose $S$ is a subset of all unary recursive functions such that $S$ and its complement are non-empty. Letting $f_{n,1}$ denote the unary function computed by program $P_n$ (if it exists). How do I show that
$$
\{n\in\mathbb{N}:f_{n,1}\in S\}
$$
is not recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [Rice's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem). This is a direct application.